# PHP Image size is less than 1mb

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, limit

curretly I am using the following to workout if the file size is less than 1MB however as the following code was from 9lession example site it said to check the size for 1mb, but if I times 1024*2 which is what they are doing here it equals not 1mb but 2048kb

saying that the size that it uploads is not in kb instead it from my understanding is bits

if you're confused so am I. I need a simple way to tell if an image is 1mb size

```
if($size<(1024*1024))
```

image that i uploaded and its size:

**Size:**10514

Also the reason I don't want to set it on a server level because we also want to do videos. We are still working our the max-size limit we will accept for videos.

Comment: That is not doing "times 1024*2". That is doing "1024*1024" which equals exactly 1MB. And what do you mean by "don't want to set it on a server level"? What does that have to do with the question? (that's a horrible idea, by the way. It's basically not setting a limit at all)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### `1MB` **==** `1048576` bytes

#### `1MB` **==** `1024` Kbytes

You question is not clear, but I will just improvise anyhow.

If you want to restrict file uploads to below `< 1MB` only!! then, since the `$_FILES` array, will output in bytes you can do the following.

```
if($_FILES['name']['size'] > 1048576){
  //You can not upload this file
}
```

Or you want want to restrict it from browser-level, you can add an attribute to your form as

```
form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1048576" />
    <input type="file" name="pictures" />
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

Offcourse, the second option  can be changed by anyone easily, and should never be used.