# No such file or directory found while optimize the image in php

Tags: php, image-optimization

I am uploading the image and that image I am optimizing but I am getting the error "No such file or directory". I am getting the error on below code.

```
  $source_img =basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

If I write `$source_img = 'assets/img/login-bg.jpg';` then it is working. I want to upload image and then optimize it.

I am getting the error

```
  Warning: getimagesize(demoimg.JPG): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\... on line 6

  Notice: Undefined variable: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\... on line 17

  Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\... on line 17
```

**HTML**

```
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
  </form>
```

**php**

```
  function compress($source, $destination, $quality) {
  $info = getimagesize($source);
  if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
  $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

  elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
  $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

  elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
  $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

  imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);
  return $destination;
  }

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $source_img =basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
  $temp = explode(".", $source_img);
  $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
  $destination_img= "assets/$newfilename";

  $d = compress($source_img, $destination_img, 90);
  }
```

Comment: It's likely because the path is not included in the source, only the basename. You probably need to send the whole path to the file into your function, not just the basename.

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Rasclatt. Actually, I am uploading Image from HTML and I am sending the only name of the image. How can I send the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this php code:

```
<?php
    function compress($source, $destination, $quality) {
    $info = getimagesize($source);
    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);
    return $destination;
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $source_img =$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
    $source_img_name =basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $temp = explode(".", $source_img_name);
    $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
    $destination_img= "assets/$newfilename";

    $d = compress($source_img, $destination_img, 90);
}
?>
```

Hope it helps. All the Best!

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.TutorialBee, Working for Me. I need one more help can we set the image size not more than 2MB?

Comment: Please check out these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567934/how-to-check-uploaded-image-size-is-greater-than-2mb-in-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472494/php-image-size-is-less-than-1mb

Comment: Thanks for your help Mr.TutorialsBee. Upvote from my side

Comment: @NarendraVerma Thanks alot :)